# Connection refused of Cloud Run on Anthos

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-anthos

Sorry for not good my English because I am a novice at English.

I am trying to run a container service on Cloud Run on Anthos because the container service is prediction by deep-learning and use much memory that is not enough for Cloud Run 2GB memory.

So at first, I tried Cloud Run on Anthos tutorial, which is below.

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/prebuilt-deploy-gke

Then I have deployed sample hello app on Cloud Run on GKE and I access by using curl like below, 
but the connection refused.

```
curl -v -H "Host: hello.default.example.com" IP_ADRESS

* Rebuilt URL to: IP_ADRESS:80/
*   Trying IP_ADRESS...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connection failed
* connect to IP_ADRESS port 80 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to IP_ADRESS port 80: connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to IP_ADRESS port 80: Connection refused
```

I deleted my cluster and service and try do that from first, but the same error happen.
What I should do?

I would appreciate you if you could help me.

Comment: Are you getting the same error in Cloud Run on Anthos?

Comment: What the error message suggests is that nothing is listening to port 80. This is explained in detailed [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message). Have you selected "External" in the connectivity section? Also, have you chosen a different service name? In that case, the hello should be replaced by your service name in the curl request